# Java: compare String var to int

Tags: java, android, string, int, compare

I request variable from the server (String xxx) and receive it properly (it equals 1).
Then I want to use it in 'if' statement, so I do :

```
if(xxx.equals(String.valueOf(1)))
```

but it doesn't work the way it supposed to be - it should be equal, but it works as it is not.

I'm out of solutions. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Whats the actual problem. Give example.

Comment: XXX doesn't just contain "1   " or "1\n" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what happens after trime `xxx`
      `if(xxx.trim().equals(String.valueOf(1)))`

Comment: That was the case. Thanks )

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (xxx.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(intValue+"") {
}
```

or

```
if (xxx.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(Integer.valueOf(xxx.trim()) == 1)
```

Rather compare them as integers than as strings.